# How do I insert text to the 1st line of a file using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

Hi I'm trying to add text to the 1st line of a file using sed
so far iv'e tried

```
#!/bin/bash
touch test
sed -i -e '1i/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;\' test
```

And this dosn't work 
also tried

```
#!/bin/bash
touch test
sed -i "1i ssl_certificate /etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;" test
```

this dosn't seem to work either
oddly when I try

```
#!/bin/bash
touch test
echo "ssl_certificate /etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;" > test
```

I get the 1st line of text to appear when i use `cat test`
but as soon as i type `sed -i "2i ssl_certificate_key /etc/example/live/example.com/privkey.pem;"`
I can't see the information that i sould do on line 2 this being ssl_certificate_key /etc/example/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

so my question to summerise

1. Can text be inserted into the 1st line of a newly created file using sed?
2. If yes whats the best way of inserting text after the 1st line of text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose you have a `file` like this:

```
one
two
```

Then to append to the first line:

```
$ sed '1 s_$_/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;_' file
one/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
two
```

To insert before the first line:

```
$ sed '1 i /etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;' file
/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
one
two
```

Or, to append after the first line:

```
$ sed '1 a /etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;' file
one
/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
two
```

Note the number `1` in those `sed` expressions - that's called [**the address**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses-overview.html#Addresses-overview) in `sed` terminology. It tells you on which **line** [the command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) that follows is to operate.

If your file doesn't contain the line you're addressing, the `sed` command won't get executed. That's why you can't insert/append on line 1, if your file is empty.

Instead of using *stream editor*, to append (to empty files), just use a shell redirection `>>`:

```
echo "content" >> file
```

Comment: How about prepend to first line?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem stems from the fact that `sed` cannot locate the line you're telling it to write at, for example:

```
touch test
sed -i -e '1i/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;\' test
```

attempts to write to insert at the line 1 of `test`, but that line doesn't exist at this point. If you've created your file as:

```
echo -en "\n" > test
sed -i '1i/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;\' test
```

it would not complain, but you'd be having an extra line. Similarly, when you call:

```
sed -i "2i ssl_certificate_key /etc/example/live/example.com/privkey.pem;"
```

you're telling `sed` to insert the following data at the line 2 which doesn't exist at that point so `sed` doesn't get to edit the file.

So, for the initial line or the last line in the file, you should not use `sed` because simple `>` and `>>` stream redirects are more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your command will work if you make sure the input file has at least one line:

```
[ "$(wc -l < test)" -gt 0 ] || printf '\n' >> test
sed -i -e '1 i/etc/example/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;\' test
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert text to the first line and put the rest on a new line using sed on macOS this worked for me

```sh
sed -i '' '1 i \
Insert
' ~/Downloads/File-path.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

## First and Last

I would assume that anyone who searched for how to insert/append text to the beginning/end of a file probably also needs to know how to do the other also.

```
cal |                            \
  gsed -E                        \
       -e     '1i\{'             \
       -e     '1i\  "lines": ['  \
       -e 's/(.*)/    "\1",/'    \
       -e '$s/,$//'              \
       -e     '$a\  ]'           \
       -e     '$a\}'
```

### Explanation

This is `cal` output piped to gnu-`sed` (called `gsed` on macOS installed via [brew.sh](https://brew.sh)) with extended RegEx (`-E`) and 6 "scripts" applied (`-e`) and line breaks escaped with `\` for readability. Scripts 1 & 2 use `1i\` to "at line 1, insert". Scripts 5 & 6 use `$a\` to "at line <last>, append". I vertically aligned the text outputs to make the code represent what is expected in the result. Scripts 3 & 4 do substitutions (the latter applying only to "line <last>"). The result is converting command output to valid JSON.

#### output

```
{
  "lines": [
    "    October 2019      ",
    "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  ",
    "       1  2  3  4  5  ",
    " 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  ",
    "13 14 15 16 17 18 19  ",
    "20 21 22 23 24 25 26  ",
    "27 28 29 30 31        ",
    "                      "
  ]
}
```

For help getting this to work with the macos/BSD version of sed, [see my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/603145/9745).